# isotropy for additive manufacturing

Tags: symmetry

Generally isotropy depends upon the direction of material properties.For the general materials it is isotropic most of the time. But for additive manufacturing the parts are built layer wise, so is it possible for it to be isotropic in nature?

Comment: Layered media are not generally isotropic, read up about hyperbolic metamaterials for example

Comment: Many standard metal processing techniques (e.g. rolling mills)  do not leave the material isotopic. The question is does that help or hurt for a given application?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is off-topic for Physics SE. Engineering SE might be a more suitable place.

Comment: "*Generally isotropy depends upon the direction of material properties*" Rather: Isotropy is the term used when there is no directionality. Otherwise anisotropic.